# Sql Server Joint Account Record Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have two tables.

**Account**

[image]
**Bvs**
[image]

**BVS DDL**

```
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BvsCheck](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [BVSCheck] [bit] NOT NULL,
  [Nic] [nchar](14) NOT NULL,
  [Account] [nchar](15) NOT NULL,
  [Comment] [nchar](10) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_BvsCheck] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [Id] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
  GO
```

**ACCOUNT DDL**

```
  GO
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO

  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO

  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Cnic] [nchar](13) NOT NULL,
  [Account] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
  [Comment] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
  [Id] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =    OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

**Goal Result**

```
200485892 
200498965
```

When search with

> 4210172668745

**Reason**

Here I just want to search those accounts in Account Table whose Nic status is 1 in Bvs further in case of this **4210172668745** Nic ,It has 3 accounts

> 200876545 , 200485892 , 200498965

But among these accounts this account **200876545** is also reference by another Nic which is **4210172668749** whose status is 0 in Bvs so that result should exclude this account.It should include only if all joint members Bvs status is 1.

**My Query**

```
  select acc.Cnic,acc.Account,bvs.BVSCheck 
  from [ QueryTest].[dbo].[Account] as acc 
  inner join BvsCheck as bvs on acc.Cnic = bvs.Nic
  where acc.account in (
    SELECT [Account] 
    FROM [ QueryTest].[dbo].[Account] 
    where Cnic = '4210172668745'
  )
```

**Result**

```
   Cnic              Account  BVSCheck
   4210172668745    200876545   1
   4210172668745    200485892   1
   4210172668745    200498965   1
   4210172668749    200876545   0
```

But again now I have to check if each account that is repeating here should have all bvs = 1.But how it could be done? 
Please help.

Comment: Please don't post images. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) You should instead post ddl, sample data and desired output so others can help.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: I have updated with DDL

Comment: How about some sample data and the desired output from that sample data? The logic here isn't difficult once we have the details of the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by comparing count of no of each account repeating  = sum of its bvs when bvscheck =1

```
   select result.Account,count(result.Account) as  
   RepeatTimes ,count(result.BVSCheck)  as BvsCheckTimes from
   (
  select acc.Cnic,acc.Account,bvs.BVSCheck from [  QueryTest].[dbo].[Account]
  as acc 
  inner join BvsCheck as bvs on acc.Cnic = bvs.Nic
  where acc.account in 
 (SELECT [Account] FROM [ QueryTest].[dbo].[Account]  where Cnic = '4210172668745')
 ) as result 

  group by result.Account having count(result.Account) =  sum(case when result.BVSCheck=1 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing of this question is pretty confusing, but I think Not Exists is what you are looking for.

```
WITH ACCT AS 
  ( SELECT '123' AS nic,
           'ABC' AS account_Number
      FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT '123' AS nic,
           'CDE' AS account_Number
      FROM dual
     UNION     
    SELECT '123' AS nic,
           'EFG' AS account_Number
      FROM dual     
  ),
  BVS AS 
  ( SELECT '123' AS cnic,
           'ABC' AS account_Number,
           0 AS bvs_check
      FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT '345' AS cnic,
           'ABC' AS account_Number,
           1 AS bvs_check
      FROM dual
     UNION     
    SELECT '123' AS cnic,
           'EFG' AS account_Number,
           1
      FROM dual     
  )
  SELECT DISTINCT ACCT.Account_Number
    FROM ACCT
   WHERE EXISTS
           ( SELECT 1
               FROM BVS BVS2
              WHERE ACCT.account_Number = BVS2.account_Number
                AND BVS2.bvs_check = 1
           )
     AND NOT EXISTS
           ( SELECT 1
               FROM BVS BVS3
              WHERE ACCT.account_Number = BVS3.account_Number
                AND BVS3.bvs_check = 0
           )
     AND ACCT.nic = '123'
```

Comment: I'm still not really following. Do you want to exclude the accounts which also have a "1" status? If so, the edit will do that.

Comment: You want to get all account numbers for a NIC which have a check of 0 for all records in BVS? Is that correct?

Comment: Then why is 200498965 in your expected results? It's check value is 0 in the second record.

Comment: Additionally, please make updates and comments based on the sample data I've provided or expand in it in this format. Images cannot be copied and pasted so that makes helping you more difficult.

Comment: the account ends with 65 and 92 are not joint accounts and both status is 1 in bvs thats why acceptable but in the case of account ends with 45 it will repeat according to my query because it is referenced by 2 nic 4210172668745 and 4210172668749 and because nic which ends with 49 has status 0 in bvs that's why this account is not acceptable .. Nic's that are linked with account must all have bvs 1 then they will be acceptable.

Comment: Okay, then I think what is in my answer should work. That is another reason why text is better than an image, I misread the screenshot in the bvs table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197361/discussion-between-taha-sultan-temuri-and-error-2646).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the sub-query -- this should be exactly the same as your query

```
 select acc.Cnic,acc.Account,bvs.BVSCheck 
 from [ QueryTest].[dbo].[Account] as acc 
 inner join BvsCheck as bvs on acc.Cnic = bvs.Nic
 where acc.Cnic = '4210172668745'
```

then just add to the where

```
 select acc.Cnic,acc.Account,bvs.BVSCheck 
 from [ QueryTest].[dbo].[Account] as acc 
 inner join BvsCheck as bvs on acc.Cnic = bvs.Nic
 where acc.Cnic = '4210172668745' and bvs.BVSCheck = 1
```

Comment: but this query does not exclude 200876545 this account

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI in the sample code you posted you do not "but this query does not exclude 200876545 this account", so I've no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: kindly see the goal state , First I have to search all accounts of the given nic in acc table then for each account I have to check if another nic is referencing that acc so check its bvs in bvs table if all its belonging nic are 1 then select this , but if any acc is not link with another nic then just check current nic bvs and if it is 1 select account

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI --- I'm sorry, your english is not good enough, I can't understand the business rules here.